# CSS: How to blur background image within the div?

Tags: html, css

I want to blur the background image that is only at the back of the `div` but if i try to add `filter:blur(10px);` in the css, only the `div` will blur and not the background. I want it to be something like this:

[image]

Here is my code:

```css
body {
  background-image: url(http://img0.mxstatic.com/wallpapers/6cba18f8e9c95b677bcc999c1e73e496_large.jpeg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.contain {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.box {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #fff;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<div class="contain" align="right">
  <div class="box">
    <h1>Header</h1>

    <p>Paragraph. Something to write...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand. In your code snippet the div doesn't have its own background at all, and there is no attempt to blur any image. Please show that code which you thought would work. Also, the code of the screenshot you added can be found completely [on codepen](http://codepen.io/ariona/pen/geFIK) have you looked at it?

Comment: [The solution by Ariona Rian](http://codepen.io/ariona/pen/geFIK) uses one completely focused image, and overlays one completely blurred image, and shows only a section of the blurred image. I wager that's your best choice as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Finally I worked out my solution:

But this solution must use javascript to get the position to feed back.

1. We made a internal background layer `.bg` embed in the `.box` container.
2. Resize the `.bg` as big as the `body`, so the background size is same.
3. Set a negative `marginTop` and `marginLeft` to the `.bg` layer, according to the `.box` position. so the `.bg` image goes coincide with the `body`.
4. Set a negative `marginBottom` to `.bg`, so the initial content in the box is placed back right.
5. Remember to set `overflow: hidden` on `.box`， and then set the `filter: blur(??px)` on the `.bg`.

To keep the effect, you need to recall the style setting statement every time you moves the `.box`.

See demo also: http://jsfiddle.net/52mk6816/

---

```js
$(function() {
  function render() {
    $('.bg').removeAttr('style').css({
      width: $('body').width(),
      height: $('body').height(),
      marginLeft: -$('.box').offset().left - 11,
      marginTop: -$('.box').offset().top - 11,
      marginBottom: -$('body').height() + $('.box').offset().top + 11,
    });
  }
  render();
  // When the window resizes, or the `.box` moves/resizes, recall the `render` function.
  $(window).resize(render);
});
```

```css
body {
  background-image: url(http://img0.mxstatic.com/wallpapers/6cba18f8e9c95b677bcc999c1e73e496_large.jpeg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.contain {
  padding: 10px;
}
.box {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.bg {
  position: relative;
  background: url(http://img0.mxstatic.com/wallpapers/6cba18f8e9c95b677bcc999c1e73e496_large.jpeg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-filter: blur(3px);
  -moz-filter: blur(3px);
  -ms-filter: blur(3px);
  filter: blur(3px);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius=10, MakeShadow=false);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contain" align="right">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="bg"></div>
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <p>Paragraph. Something to write...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Here comes another implementation, using background position instead of positioning the `.bg` layer: http://jsfiddle.net/02oLn3zt/

Answer (score 1):

I believe the easier solution would be to add `backdrop-filter`, like:

`backdrop-filter: blur(20px)`

for example:

```css
.main{
 width:100vw;
 height:100vh;
 background:url("https://source.unsplash.com/buF62ewDLcQ");
 background-size: cover;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}

.box{
padding:10vh 10vw;
backdrop-filter:blur(20px) brightness(110%);
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
<div class="box">My Content here</div>
</div>
```

you can read a good article about it at: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/backdrop-filter/

or see more about the spec here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter

Answer (score 0):

In your satuastion, you dont actually add the blur effect to your body backgroud, you need to add it to your `.box`.

To get the effect you are looking for, make a png file with white background and a 50% or 60% opacity to get the transparent effect. Use that PNG as your `.box` background and apply blur to the box:

```
.box{

border: 1px solid #fff;
border-radius: 10px;
padding: 10px;
width: 200px;
height:200px;
background-image:url('back.png');
position: relative;
z-index: 1
display: block;
-webkit-filter: blur(5px);
-moz-filter: blur(5px);
-o-filter: blur(5px);
-ms-filter: blur(5px);
filter: blur(5px);
}
```

back.png is file you will be creating as the `.box` background.

You can also apply CSS `opacity` to get more transparency